# RESTful Application .htaccess error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rest, httprequest

I'm working on a backbone.js application (just for reference) and I can submit requests to `controller.php` for processing. I have a switch statement on the `REQUEST_METHOD` and it works as expected with `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

However, when I use the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?controller/([^/]+)$ /controller.php?id=$1 [L]
```

...and pass to `controller/5` instead of `controller.php?id=5` I get a 405 error - method not allowed.

I've been digging through Google and asking colleagues and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of your .htaccess looks wrong.

If you only have methods 0 to 9 it would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/controller/([0-9])$ /controller.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

or in general:

```
RewriteRule ^/controller/(.*)$ /controller.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

and in this case everything after the controller/ will be passed as value ($1) for the id parameter.

If it is working when you call `controller.php?id=5` it should also work when called as `controller/5`

Comment: The rewriterule could have anything at the end - I'm using the ID as an example.